# Simular clique do mouse

Tags: delphi, eventos-do-mouse

Preciso simular o clique do *mouse*, porém não posso utilizar `PostMessage` nem `mouse_event`. Existe alguma outra maneira de enviar o clique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a API [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx).

> Sintetiza as teclas digitadas, movimentos de mouse e cliques de botão.
>
> **Obs**: Esta função está sujeita a [***UIPI***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx). Os pedidos são autorizados a
>   injetar a *entrada* apenas em aplicações que estão em um nível de
>   integridade igual ou inferior.

Supondo que você deseja primeiramente mover o cursor para uma ponto especifico, deve-se usar coordenadas absolutas no intervalo entre *0* e *65535*, portanto, para calcular corretamente as coordenadas da tela, use a seguinte função:

```
function ObterCoordenada(const Indice, Posicao: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := (65535 div (GetSystemMetrics (Indice) -1)) * Posicao;
end;
```

Agora, a função responsável por mover o cursor e simular o clique com o botão esquerdo com a função `SendInput`:

```
procedure SimularClick(const X, Y: Integer);
var
Entrada: array [0..1] of TInput;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@Entrada, SizeOf(Entrada));
  // Primeiramente move o cursor do mouse a uma coordenada especifica, em Pixels!
  Entrada[0].Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
  Entrada[0].mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE or MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
  Entrada[0].mi.dx := ObterCoordenada(SM_CXSCREEN, X);
  Entrada[0].mi.dy := ObterCoordenada(SM_CYSCREEN, Y);
  SendInput(1, Entrada[0], sizeof(TInput)); // Envia o pedido

  // Realiza o click com o botão esquerdo do mouse
  Entrada[1].Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
  Entrada[1].mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

  SendInput(1, Entrada[1], sizeof(TInput));   // Envia o pedido
end;
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SimularClick(625, 486); // Onde "625" é X e "486", Y
end;
```

Comment: Também não posso usar sendinput pois o programa fez um hook para bloqueio da função.

http://pastebin.com/q8JmP6ix, o que eu posso fazer para bypassear este hook?

Comment: @Fake Complicado, porque o *hooking* trabalha a baixo nível, para anular a atividade do program que intercepta as chamadas do mouse, você terá que finalizá-lo ou impedir que ele instale o *hook* , ou seja, anular a função `SetWindowsHookEx`. [Aqui](http://www.forum-invaders.com.br/vb/showthread.php/30995-TUTORIAL-Code-Injection?s=da6af492b3f1f693aae45e08aba565d8) fala algo sobre *code injection*, [aqui](http://www.elitepvpers.com/forum/pw-hacks-bots-cheats-exploits/239239-direct-injection-codes-delphi-c-autoit.html) tem outra abordagem.